# Replace dropdown options with only those that match values in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am struggling with doing this in raw JavaScript. Currently I have two dropdowns a parent and a child like so:

```
<select id="state" title="" name="state">
     <option selected="selected" value="Open" label="Open">Open</option>
     <option value="Closed" label="Closed">Closed</option>
 </select>



 <select id="status" title="" name="status">
      <option value="Open_New" label="New">New</option>
      <option value="Open_Assigned" label="Assigned">Assigned</option>
      <option value="Closed_Closed" label="Closed">Closed</option>
      <option value="Open_Pending Input" label="Pending External Input">Pending External Input</option>
      <option value="Open_Pending" label="Pending Internal Input">Pending Internal Input</option>
      <option value="Closed_Duplicate" label="Duplicate">Duplicate</option>
      <option value="Open_CARD" label="CARD">CARD</option>
      <option value="Open_Open" label="Open">Open</option>
      <option value="Open_DAD" label="DAD">DAD</option>
      <option value="Closed_Rejected" label="Rejected">Rejected</option>
   </select>
```

And the child dropdown values are selected based on the parent dropdown values name with and an underscore:

```
  function updateDynamicEnum(field, subfield){
        if(document.getElementById(subfield) != null){
             var selector = document.getElementById(subfield);
    var de_key = document.getElementById(field).value;

    var current = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < selector.length; i++) {
        if (selector.options[i].selected) current.push(selector.options[i].value);
    }


    if(de_entries[subfield]  == null){
       de_entries[subfield] =  new Array;
       for (var i=0; i<selector.options.length; i++){
            de_entries[subfield][selector.options[i].value] = selector.options[i].text;
       }
    }

    document.getElementById(subfield).innerHTML = '';

    for (var key in de_entries[subfield]) {
        if(key.indexOf(de_key+'_') == 0){
            selector.options[selector.options.length] = new Option(de_entries[subfield][key], key);
        }
    }

    for (var key in current) {
        for (var i = 0; i < selector.length; i++) {
            if(selector.options[i].value == current[key])
            selector[i].selected = true;
        }
    }
  }
```

What I need to do is change this code so that child dropdown values are not selected based on the key name with an underscore but selected when they are part of an array that is passed in. The array is called child_strings and looks like this:

```
   'open' => array(
    'Open_New',
    'Open_Assigned',
    'Open_Pending Input',
    'Open_Pending',
    'Open_CARD',
    'Open_Open',
    'Open_DAD'
),
 'closed' => array(
    'Open_Assigned',
    'Closed_Closed',
    'Closed_Duplicate',
    'Closed_Rejected',
),
```

my new code looks like this:

```
function updateDynamicEnum(field, subfield, child_strings){

 //console.log(child_strings);

if(document.getElementById(subfield) != null){

    var de_key = document.getElementById(field).value;
    var child = document.getElementById(subfield);

    var current = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
        if (child.options[i].selected) current.push(child.options[i].value);
    }

    if(de_entries[subfield]  == null){
        de_entries[subfield] =  new Array;
        for (var i=0; i<child.options.length; i++){
            de_entries[subfield][child.options[i].value] = child.options[i].text;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById(subfield).innerHTML = '';

    //this part needs changes 
    for (var key in de_entries[subfield]) {
        if(key.indexOf(de_key+'_') == 0){
            child.options[child.options.length] = new Option(de_entries[subfield][key], key);
        }
    }
```

But struggling to see how to check child_strings and determine if the vales is in that array etc..

Comment: why is jQuery a keyword if you dont use it?

Comment: i am open to a Jquery solution if its much simpler

Comment: your whole code would be :) never mind

Comment: I never wrote the original code thats the issue, I would have done it in jquery but i really just want to quickly change it to do what I need.

Comment: @user794846, uhm nope you actually want us to change it so it does what you need. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the answer out for myself but if somebody can post a better one please go ahead.

```
      function updateDynamicEnum(field, subfield, child_strings){

if(document.getElementById(subfield) != null){

    var de_key = document.getElementById(field).value;
    var child = document.getElementById(subfield);

    var current = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
        if (child.options[i].selected) current.push(child.options[i].value);
    }

    if(de_entries[subfield]  == null){
        de_entries[subfield] =  new Array;
        for (var i=0; i<child.options.length; i++){
            de_entries[subfield][child.options[i].value] = child.options[i].text;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById(subfield).innerHTML = '';

    var arg = child_strings[de_key];

    for (var key in de_entries[subfield]) {

        if(isInArray(key,arg)){

            child.options[child.options.length] = new Option(de_entries[subfield][key], key);
        }
    }

      for (var key in current) {
        for (var i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
            if(child.options[i].value == current[key])
                child[i].selected = true;
        }
    } 
}
 /*Checks if value is in an array*/
function isInArray(value, array) {
    return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
}

}
```